# Using gatsby and search parameters Oauth

Tags: javascript, oauth, callback, gatsby

I am trying to get Oauth with Google working on Gatsby. When I get the callback from Google it redirects to my backend which in turn redirects to my frontend. The callback should include a token which I can use to get a JWT token on my backend.

However when I use to props.location to extract the token from the url I get nothing. I can see the URL, but no search parameter. When I open the networking tab in the google chrome developer tools I can see that the request is made to the URL including the token I need. How can I access this token in Gatsby?

When I console.log props.location I can see the base url for my frontend end page, but not the search parameter. I tried using the UseLocation hook from @reach/router package, but no success either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.